# wslview fails outside working directory

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I tried to use wslview to open valgrinds dhal webinterface at /usr/libexec/valgrind/dh_view.html.

```
wslview /example/path/file
```

I recieve the following error:

```
Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start "/usr/libexec/valgrind/dh_view.html"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Everything works just fine when I specify a file in my working directory.
How can I use wslview without cd?

Comment: `wslview` doesn't work at the directory level by design so It's unclear what you expect the output to be on an entire directory. Why are you avoiding be explicit with the filename when you call this utility?

Comment: Sorry I didn't write it clearly, but I specified the file. For my case:"/usr/libexec/valgrind/dh_view.html", hence its appearance in the error message.

Comment: How do you install wslview in the first place? I am on Linux for WSL and sudo apt install wslview doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in the latest release of the `wslu` package.  I can reproduce your issue before upgrading, but after upgrading it works fine.

You don't mention which distribution you are using, but [see here](https://wslutiliti.es/wslu/install.html) for installation instructions for various distributions.

For Ubuntu, to upgrade via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wslutilities/wslu
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: +1 : It only took 2 years for it to arrive : https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu/issues/118

Comment: Adding the repo and upgrading fixed it. I was running Ubuntu 20.04.4 and actually just installed wslu. The repo was really necassary. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @harrymc Ah, that's why I didn't find it.  Searched the issues list for *"system cannot find the file specified"*, but it was in Chinese in the report.